# how to determine if 2 APKs with same package name is different?

Tags: android, hash, package, apk

Is there a way to determine if 2 APKs with same package name is different (assumming that they are coming from 2 different market)? Does getting the hash of the applications would help me? Thanks

Comment: If you compare the hash of the apk's and the size of the apk's and check they're both equal I think that would be almost 100% accurate. It would be insanely hard to break that even if you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing a hash or digital signature on the APKs will tell you if they're exactly identical.  If you want to know whether they are functionally equivalent, then you'll have to extract the contents and examine the resources and executable files.  If they have the same names, that would give me about 50% confidence that they are equivalent.  If they implement all the same classes and methods (by name), I'd be about 90% certain they are functionally equivalent.

How to calculate an MD5 signature of a file on Linux:

```
md5sum filename
```

How to calculate an MD5 signature of a file on Mac or BSD:

```
md5 filename
```

How to calculate an MD5/SHA1/SHA512 signature of a file using OpenSSL:

```
openssl dgst -md5 filename
openssl dgst -sha1 filename
openssl dgst -sha512 filename
```

How to calculate a signature across all the files in a directory:

```
cat * | md5sum
cat * | openssl dgst -sha512
```

Comment: ahh. but I am thinking, an apk is an archive right? which means several files is stored in that. does md5 or sha1 has the capability to get the total hash of all that files?

Comment: The archive is just .ZIP, which is well-defined.  If you copy a .ZIP archive from one machine to another, it should have the same md5 or sha1 signature.  That's exactly identical.  On the other hand, if you take the same collection of uncompressed files and zip it separately on two different platforms, they may not have the same exact content, due to filesystem differences.  Then you'd have to hash the files one-by-one.  But once you're doing that, you may as well compare the bytes directly.

Comment: Yes, you can get a total hash of all the files.  Either you can hash the archive itself, or you can stream all the bytes through the signature utility by doing something like: cat * | md5sum -- but, as mentioned, due to filesystem differences, this may not yield the same result on two different machines.  (Although it gave the same hash just now when I copied a directory from a Mac to a Linux box and back again.)

Comment: Wouldn't md5 (or sha1, or any other similar algorithm) mean it needs to go through the entire file's bytes? If it is, isn't it better to just compare one byte after another, to the other file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have many experience with android but can't you compare the size of the APK's ?

Comment: I was just thinking that since Hash like Sha1 and Md5 can be used to tell if 2 files with same filename are different, maybe I could do the same thing with APK.

Answer (score 0):

you can use androgaurd :after down load it from gitHub
write the next command in terminal:

```
python androsim.py -i first.apk second.apk -c ZLIB -n
```

It explained [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/part-2-deep-analysis-using-androguard-tools-2/)